# Show different layers from pixelated object ( Block tools > Pixelate object )

Tags: layers

I'm working on some voxel art and i use blender to get my 3D objects to blocks so i can re-create it in different software.

It would help me a lot if i could hide / show different layers on the Y axis.

Is there a option to show for example only all blocks on the first layer of blocks. After that the second layer etc.

So for example lets take a pyramid. If you would "Block tools > Pixelate object" it Blender would create blocks as in;

Bottom layer: 16x16 blocks
Second layer: 15x15 blocks
Third layer: 14x14 blocks

I would like to be able to show the bottom layer and hide the layers on top of that. After i've recreated the first layer i would like to hide it and only show the second layer and so on.

It there a option within blender to actually do this?

Comment: I would consider either the Build modifier https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/build.html or the Mask modifier https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html (or both)